# Swift 2.1 - How to pass index path row of collectionView cell to segue

Tags: ios, swift

From the main controller that I have integrated collection view, I want to pass selected cell index path to another view controller (detail view)
so I can use it for updating a specific record.

I have the following working `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "RecipeDetailVC" {

        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? RecipeDetailVC 

        if let recipeCell = sender as? Recipe {
            detailVC!.recipe = recipeCell

        }
    }
}
```

And I've tried including `let indexPath = collection.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell)` but I get `Could not cast value of type 'xxx.Recipe' (0x7fae7580c950) to 'UICollectionViewCell'` at runtime.

I also have `performSegueWithIdentifier("RecipeDetailVC", sender: recipeCell)` and I wonder if I can use this to pass the selected cell's index path but not sure I can add this index to the sender.

Comment: When you call perform segue make the sender the object you want to send, not the cell itself.

Comment: You're saying I can make the indexpath as a sender instead? In this case, How do I receive this index path in the destination controller?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about the hierarchy of your collectionViewCell. But I think the `sender` maybe not a cell. Try to use

```
let indexPath = collection.indexPathForCell(sender.superView as! UICollectionViewCell)
```

or

```
let indexPath = collection.indexPathForCell(sender.superView!.superView as! UICollectionViewCell)
```

That may work.

Comment: Thanks but I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote up a quick example to show you, it uses a tableView but the concept is the same:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var things = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] // These can be anything...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let objectForCell = self.things[indexPath.row] // Regular stuff
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let objectAtIndex = self.things[indexPath.row]
    let indexOfObject = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: indexOfObject)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "next" {
        // On this View Controller make an Index property, like var index
        let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        nextVC.index = sender as! Int
    }
}   
}
```

Here you can see you get the actual object itself and use it as the sender in the perform segue method. You can access it in prepareForSegue and assign it directly to a property on the destination view controller.

Comment: I'm able send data over to other view controller but not the actual index number. Can I just send the indexPath to other view controller? And if can, how can I receive this indexPath in the destination view controller?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the passing of the index and with a comment on assigning it to a property in prepareForSegue.

Comment: I get `Could not cast value of type 'Project.Recipe' (0x7fedc2e7bb30) to 'NSNumber'` when I do nextVC!.index = sender as! Int
I've created index variable in the destination view controller

Comment: If your property is an NSNumber then create one from the sender in prepareForSegue using the Int initializer of NSNumber: NSNumber(integer: sender as! Int)

Comment: My property is an Int and I think the index is type of NSNumber. 
I've tried this instead given my property in Int `nextVC!.index = Int(sender as! NSNumber)` but I still get `Could not cast value of type 'Project.Recipe' (0x7fc9d3f0cfb0) to 'NSNumber`